# VSCodium in Manjaro/Gnome changes keyboard shortcut

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, vscodium

I use Manjaro/Gnome and had Super+F to start the file manager (Files). I decided to give it a try to VSCodium and now the shortcut starts VSCodium, not Files.
I searched in Gnome Settings>Keyboard and the shortcut assigned to Files is still Super+F, but it is not working, all I get is to start VSCodium.
Any ideas on how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found that VSCodium or VS Code installation sets themselves as the default application to deal with directories.
To go back to default/personal shortcuts you must edit `mimeinfo.cache` found in the `/usr/share/applications` directory.

Look for the line
`inode/directory=codium.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;ranger.desktop;`
and delete `codium,desktop;`... Logout and login again.

That will fix it.